# same "ItemsSource" for every combobox in a UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml

I have several comboboxes in a window / userControl. And I am setting the ItemsSource from the parent, but only specifying the name of the combobox.
Since I don't want to do that for each one (because I cannot repeate the combobox names), how can I implement this for all items of a kind (Combobox in this case) inside this userControl?

In UserControl code behind

```
    public object multiSwitchListDataContext {
        get { return multiSwitchCombobox.DataContext; }
        set
        {
            multiSwitchCombobox.DataContext = value; 
            multiSwitchCombobox.ItemsSource = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

In mainWindow CS

```
    (myUserControl).multiSwitchListDataContext = multiSwitchList;
```

In userControl xaml

```
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="multiSwitchCombobox"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      EditValueChanged="EditValueChanged"/>
```

Comment: You can loop all controls in your parent control and then check if the type is ComboBox and then set the source.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know the names of controls, this is what `Binding`s were designed to cover. Can you post some code to show what you have tried?

Comment: What is multiSwitchList?

Comment: a List in the mainWindow cs where my comboBox reads the values from

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a full answer for your current issue because there isn't enough information/code to provide one but the following example should hopefully help you sort it.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Very important to get the binding working.
    this.DataContext = this;
}

// The property to bind to, you should choose a better type than object.
public IList<object> MyList
{
    get { return (IList<object>)GetValue(MyListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyListProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyList", typeof(IList<object>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

You should then find by setting the MyList property in your code it will populate the `ComboBox` with the values in MyList.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem comes because I have this comboboxes in the UserControl, and the objects list in the mainWindow...

Comment: @Carlosss that is still entirely possible but it just becomes more complicated. You need to expose a property on the UserControl like ItemsSource that can be bound in your MainWindow.xaml file, this should then cover what you need

Comment: I am sorry I still dont get it. The Binding is made in the userControl to all its Comboboxes, but the list I need to bind to these comboboxes exists in the mainwindow.cs

Comment: @carloss does your UserControl do much more than control a ComboBox? i.e. does it render other controls, if not then you could just inherit from CombBox and then you can bind to the ItemsSource property inside the MainWindow.xaml